# Changing rowIndex of chart inside Dashboard

Tags: lightningchart

I'm using a Dashboard to synchronize the X-axis of multiple charts. When creating an instance of the Dashboard, I specify that it should have 6 rows. In my application, the user can add or remove charts. I encountered an issue when removing a chart. If the user adds all 6 charts and then decides to remove the fourth one, and then the user decides to add a new chart again, it should have the last position (with rowIndex 5).

**How can I update the rowIndex for charts 5 and 6 if the user removes the fourth chart?**